# Instead of an old work, can I cite a new work that shares an author and cites it?

Tags: citations, review-articles

In my research field (operations research), several works have been published in the last couple of years by different authors that cover most of the recent developments in the field.
I’m writing a review paper and even though I read and used a couple of papers dated as far back as the 90s (mainly for my introduction and review), I want all references to be from 2010 or later.

I would like to write something like:

> Ref. 3 discussed branch & bound and dynamic programming approaches for KP, MKP and some of its variants.

Reference 3 is *Kellerer, Pferschy, and Pisinger (2004)*.
Another paper, namely *Puchinger, Raidl, and Pferschy (2010)* shares one of its authors with Reference 3 and also cites it.

My question is: Instead of citing Reference 3 as it is, can I cite *Puchinger, Raidl, and Pferschy (2010)* because it is more recent?

Comment: *I want all reference to be dated from 2010-2019* --- Just a passing thought, but wouldn't some readers suspect that you were not very thorough in your review if all your references were only from the past decade?

Comment: To follow-up on my comment, I spent a few seconds just now googling for a survey paper (googled the phrase "survey paper" along with a random math topic, "convex geometry") and I found [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6da1/901c20467c5169499c08438cf0f37b3aec47.pdf) published in 1999, and I tried to imagine how thorough the coverage would be if all references before 1989 were omitted. (Not very thorough was my conclusion.) Incidentally, note that this survey paper is much narrower in scope than "operations research".

Comment: @DaveLRenfro, Thanks.. I had to edit my question to be more explanatory, i am not trying to omit the works done at the early stages of the research, I am only asking about the possibility of using the recent researches done to reference the old research by citing the new instead of the old provided( same field, same/different authors, old work is cited in new work). Thank you

Comment: Still, why "instead" when you can cite both? "This first appeared in [1]; see [2] for a modern exposition" is a standard way to proceed when you want to cite a newer source [2] along with an old one [1].

Comment: @darijgrinberg, understood.. but I want all the sources listed in my reference to be dated from 2010-later, so how do I go about this ?

Comment: Is the 9 key on your keyboard broken?

Comment: Before anyone can give a meaningful answer, you need to answer a question: _why_? Why do you "want all references to be from 2010 or later"?

Comment: I assume that the specific information for which you cited Reference 3 is also covered in the newer paper that you want to cite instead. But you didn't actually say that. If the assumption is wrong, then of course you need to cite the old paper that actually contains the information in question. Even if my assumption is right, I see no good reason not to cite both papers.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against this as it seems artificial. The year you give isn't some magic number and citing only recent work doesn't give you any advantage.

But there is a deeper reason in this case, I think. Just because a new paper cites an older one doesn't mean that the newer one advances the older one in every relevant direction. Another way to think of it is that the ideas in the new paper don't actually "contain" all of the ideas in the older one. Someone wanting a good overview of the field - the purpose of a review article - will probably need to go see what those additional ideas are, but if you don't point to them their only pointer is indirect through the paper you do cite. This makes the serious reader's job harder.

You seem to be giving an annotated bibliography, I see no reason to truncate it. The annotations, if well done, will help a reader decide whether to go to any given paper you include.

Comment: I suppose that one could write an 'update' review, covering just the last $n$ years worth of work, but that point should be made explicit as well as having citations of the last few major review papers in the field. Slightly different focus of the paper, and it would be written a bit differently.

Answer (score 1):

Cite them both.  Covers various aspects.